# What is the reference point for measuring angles in OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, vector, angle, opticalflow

I'm trying to infer an object's direction of movement using dense optical flow in OpenCV. I'm using `calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` to get flow coordinates and `cartToPolar()` to acquire vector angles which would indicate direction.

To interpret the results I need to know the reference point for measuring the angle. I have found [this](https://codeyarns.com/2014/02/26/carttopolar-in-opencv/) blog post indicating that the range of angles is 360°. That tells me that the angle measurement would go along the lines of the unit circle. I couldn't make out much more than that.

The documentation for `cartToPolar()` doesn't cover this and my attempts at testing it have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the angle produced by `cartToPolar()` is in reference to the unit circle rotated clockwise by 90° centered on the image coordinate starting point in the top left corner. [It would look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTeL.png)

I came to this conclusion by using the [dense optical flow example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) provided by OpenCV. I replaced the line `hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2` with `hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi` to get correct angle conversion from radians. Then I tested a video with people moving from top right to bottom left and vice versa. I sampled the dominant color with GIMP and got RGB values which I converted to HSV values. Hue value corresponds to the angle in degrees.

People moving from top right to bottom left produced an angle of about 300° and people moving the other way round produced an angle of about 120°. This hinted at the way the unit circle is positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp#L266), `fastAtan32f` is used to compute the angles. and that seems to be a `atan2` implementation.